# How to round up integer number to multiple of 10

Tags: python

I found how to round down or up a floating number to the next or previous integer number, but this is my issue:

Suppose I have these numbers:

```
12
11
10
27
29
25
16
```

I'm going to
round up to the nearest 10. If number has 0 in the last digit, then pass it.

I saw something like this but they round down:

```py
import math
math.ceil(12)
round(12)
```

Expected output:

```
20
20
10
30
30
30
20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `ceil` in the math library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil

you can divide the number as a parameter by 10^(digit precision desired), then multiply the result by that number to round to a particular decimal place:
math.ceil(13 / 10) * 10 = 20

Answer (score 0):

Bit cheap and cheerful, but:

```
def roundup10( n ):
    if n % 10 == 0: return n
    else          : return n + 10 - n % 10

for x in [ 12, 11, 10, 27, 29, 25, 16 ]: print( roundup10( x ) )
```

Output:

```
20
20
10
30
30
30
20
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def roundup(n):
    n = n - n % 10
    return n
```

Comment: How can subtracting a number possibly round up?

Comment: for the negative numbers add: if n<0 n = n-n%10 + 10.